# MYSQL SELECT DISTINCT value from and column and its corresponding value from another

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a column in a database which i use the below code to get the distinct values from that column

```
"SELECT DISTINCT category FROM galleryinfo"
```

I have another column with the path to the relevant image.

So my question is how do i get the unique/distinct values from category and it corresponding path from the other column.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
id    path           category
1     img1           car
2     img2           car
3     img3           truck
4     img4           truck
5     img5           bike
```

The result i require would be

```
img1   car     
img3   truck   
img5   bike
```

Comment: If the path is distinct with respect to the category, just use `SELECT DISTINCT category, path FROM galleryinfo`. If that doesn't do what you need, please post some sample data and expected results.

Comment: I have tryed that but as every path is unique it displays all the values in the path column

Comment: add sample data with your desired result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY query to reduce the result to one row per distinct category:

```
SELECT category, path FROM galleryinfo GROUP BY category
```

The problem with this is that it's arbitrary *which* path this query returns.  In fact, in most SQL implementations, this is an illegal query and results in an error.  MySQL is more lenient, but it will return an arbitrary path from those matching the category (in practice, it chooses the path from the first row with respect to physical storage, but this is not documented or guaranteed).

You can choose either the `MIN(path)` or `MAX(path)`, or concatenate all paths per category together into one string with `GROUP_CONCAT(path)`, but that's about it.